# Suggestions to optimize a simple Scala foldLeft over multiple values?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold, optimization

I'm re-implementing some code (a simple Bayesian inference algorithm, but that's not really important) from Java to Scala. I'd like to implement it in the most performant way possible, while keeping the code clean and functional by avoiding mutability as much as possible.

Here is the snippet of the Java code:

```
    // initialize
    double lP  = Math.log(prior);
    double lPC = Math.log(1-prior);

    // accumulate probabilities from each annotation object into lP and lPC
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        float prob = annotation.getProbability();
        if (isValidProbability(prob)) {
            lP  += logProb(prob);
            lPC += logProb(1 - prob);
        }
    }
```

Pretty simple, right? So I decided to use Scala foldLeft and map methods for my first try. Since I have two values I'm accumulating over, the accumulator is a tuple:

```
    val initial  = (math.log(prior), math.log(1-prior))
    val probs    = annotations map (_.getProbability)
    val (lP,lPC) = probs.foldLeft(initial) ((r,p) => {
      if(isValidProbability(p)) (r._1 + logProb(p), r._2 + logProb(1-p)) else r
    })
```

Unfortunately, this code performs about 5 times slower than Java (using a simple and imprecise metric; just called the code 10000 times in a loop). One defect is pretty clear; we are traversing lists twice, once in the call to map and the other in the foldLeft. So here's a version that traverses the list once.

```
    val (lP,lPC) = annotations.foldLeft(initial) ((r,annotation) => {
      val  p = annotation.getProbability
      if(isValidProbability(p)) (r._1 + logProb(p), r._2 + logProb(1-p)) else r
    })
```

This is better! It performs about 3 times worse than the Java code. My next hunch was that there is probably some cost involved in creating all the new tuples in each step of the fold. So I decided to try a version that traverses the list twice, but without creating tuples.

```
    val lP = annotations.foldLeft(math.log(prior)) ((r,annotation) => {
       val  p = annotation.getProbability
       if(isValidProbability(p)) r + logProb(p) else r
    })
    val lPC = annotations.foldLeft(math.log(1-prior)) ((r,annotation) => {
      val  p = annotation.getProbability
      if(isValidProbability(p)) r + logProb(1-p) else r
    })
```

This performs about the same as the previous version (3 times slower than the Java version). Not really surprising, but I was hopeful.

So my question is, is there a faster way to implement this Java snippet in Scala, while keeping the Scala code clean, avoiding unnecessary mutability and following Scala idioms? I do expect to use this code eventually in a concurrent environment, so the value of keeping immutability may outweigh the slower performance in a single thread.

Comment: Do you have lazy datastructures in scala? If so, you should be able to avoid multiple passes.

Comment: @Marcin: yes, Scala collections provide a [`view` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) that makes this very easy.

Answer (score 4):

First, some of your penalty may come from the type of collection you're using.  But most of it is probably the object creation which you actually do not avoid by running the loop twice, since the numbers have to be boxed.

Instead, you can create a mutable class that accumulates the values for you:

```
class LogOdds(var lp: Double = 0, var lpc: Double = 0) {
  def *=(p: Double) = {
    if (isValidProbability(p)) {
      lp += logProb(p)
      lpc += logProb(1-p)
    }
    this  // Pass self on so we can fold over the operation
  }
  def toTuple = (lp, lpc)
}
```

Now although you *can* use this unsafely, you don't have to.  In fact, you can just fold over it.

```
annotations.foldLeft(new LogOdds()) { (r,ann) => r *= ann.getProbability } toTuple
```

If you use this pattern, all the mutable unsafety is tucked away inside the fold; it never escapes.

Now, you can't do a parallel fold, but you *can* do an aggregate, which is like a fold with an extra operation to combine pieces.  So you add the method

```
def **(lo: LogOdds) = new LogOdds(lp + lo.lp, lpc + lo.lpc)
```

to `LogOdds` and then

```
annotations.aggregate(new LogOdds())(
  (r,ann) => r *= ann.getProbability,
  (l,r) => l**r
).toTuple
```

and you'll be good to go.

(Feel free to use non-mathematical symbols for this, but since you're basically multiplying probabilities, the multiplication symbol seemed more likely to give an intuitive idea for what is going on than incorporateProbability or somesuch.)

Comment: Why can't he do a parallel fold? He's just adding values, which is commutative and associative.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - Because he needs to do a `foldLeft` (`(U,T)=>U`), not just fold (`(U,U)=>U`), and `foldLeft` can't sensibly be accumulated in parallel.  That's why `aggregate` exists.

Comment: @Rex - I don't get it either. If you do the filter first on validity (and ignore the initialization of `lp` and `lpc` which is just a simple addition) this looks associative to me. You can arbitrarily parallelize what is a `Foldable[A : Monoid].sum`

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - You can `map`, then `filter`, then `fold`, or you can `aggregate`.  One step is generally faster than three.  `aggregate` is also a parallel operation.

Comment: Ah, ok, I had forgotten about the `map` step.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement a tail-recursive method which will be converted to a while-loop by the compiler, hence should be as fast as the Java version. Or, you could just use a loop - there's no law against it, if it just uses local variables in a method (see extensive use in the Scala collections source code, for example).

```
def calc(lst: List[Annotation], lP: Double = 0, lPC: Double = 0): (Double, Double) = {
  if (lst.isEmpty) (lP, lPC)
  else {
    val prob = lst.head.getProbability
    if (isValidProbability(prob)) 
      calc(lst.tail, lP + logProb(prob), lPC + logProb(1 - prob))
    else 
      calc(lst.tail, lP, lPC)
  }
}
```

The advantage of folding is that it's parallelizable, which may lead to it being faster than the Java version on a multi-core machine (see other answers).

Comment: `List` is not efficiently parallelizable

Comment: @oxbow that makes sense; if parallelizing it's better to ensure you're using a class with fast random access like `Vector`.

Answer (score 2):

As a kind of side note: you can avoid traversing the list twice more idiomatically by using [`view`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html):

```
val probs = annotations.view.map(_.getProbability).filter(isValidProbability)

val (lP, lPC) = ((logProb(prior), logProb(1 - prior)) /: probs) {
   case ((pa, ca), p) => (pa + logProb(p), ca + logProb(1 - p))
}
```

This probably isn't going to get you better performance than your third version, but it feels more elegant to me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion regd view(), especially with the example.

Comment: There is probably some overhead in creating the lazy data structure required for the view. My simple benchmarking experiments suggest that there is a cost involved. But I agree on the elegance aspect entirely :)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's address the performance issue: *there's no way to implement it as fast as Java except by using while loops*. Basically, JVM cannot optimize the Scala loop to the extent it optimizes the Java one. The reasons for that are even a concern among the JVM folk because it gets in the way of they parallel library efforts as well.

Now, back to Scala performance, you can also use `.view` to avoid creating a new collection in the `map` step, but I think the `map` step will always lead to worse performance. The thing is, you are converting the collection into one parameterized on `Double`, which must be boxed and unboxed.

However, there's one possible way of optimizing it: making it parallel. If you call `.par` on `annotations` to make it a parallel collection, you can then use `fold`:

```
val parAnnot = annotations.par
val lP = parAnnot.map(_.getProbability).fold(math.log(prior)) ((r,p) => {
   if(isValidProbability(p)) r + logProb(p) else r
})
val lPC = parAnnot.map(_.getProbability).fold(math.log(1-prior)) ((r,p) => {
  if(isValidProbability(p)) r + logProb(1-p) else r
})
```

To avoid a separate `map` step, use `aggregate` instead of `fold`, as suggested by Rex.

For bonus points, you could use `Future` to make both computations run in parallel. I suspect you'll get better performance by bringing the tuples back and running it in one go, though. You'll have to benchmark this stuff to see what works better.

On parallel colletions, it might pay off to first `filter` it for valid annotations. Or, perhaps, `collect`.

```
val parAnnot = annottions.par.view map (_.getProbability) filter (isValidProbability(_)) force;
```

or

```
val parAnnot = annotations.par collect { case annot if isValidProbability(annot.getProbability) => annot.getProbability }
```

Anyway, benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to interact with the scala collections library without boxing. So what are primitive `double`s in Java would be being continually boxed and unboxed in the `fold` operation, even if you weren't wrapping them in a `Tuple2` (which *is* specialized - but of course you are already paying the performance overhead of creating new objects each time).

Comment: It's really annoying that the lowest level (the one with the most iterations) has always to work on arrays of primitive types if you want performance. Are there any possible abstractions?